# Command line argument to Delete all the TFS builds?

Tags: tfs

I'm using the Build Explorer to delete our project's builds. It's taking forever because it's 'timing out' trying to delete the label and drop location (now that the drop location doesn't exist any more).

So, I'm hoping to do this via the command line to see if I get more love.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you on the 2005 or 2008 client? I seem to remember the 2008 client dealing better w/ drop location already deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, see the following HowTo on MSDN.

- [How to: Delete a Completed Build (Command-Line)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337656.aspx)

However, I'm not sure that this is going to improve the situation for you as it basically does the same server calls that the UI does.  Give it a try anyway. In the meantime I'll go ask a few folks and I'll edit this answer if we come up with anything to help you with your timeout issues.

Comment: At least with a command-line call you can stick a load of them in a batch file and leave them running overnight (or whatever) - this is assuming they're doing anything at all when they 'time out'.

Answer (score 0):

The [TFS Build Manager](http://www.codeplex.com/TFSBuildManager) utility will let you multi-select and delete. It still works serially but at least it's only one manual step.